# Changing Data in a Plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist

Hey, alright so I have a .plist that looks like;

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>Item 0</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Jero</string>
    <key>Initiative</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>EditThis</key>
    <false/>
 </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

In the app I have it so that when one of the rows (The data is put in a UITableView) is selected it pushes to a new view controller.  I would like also to set the 'EditThis' boolean to yes, so the edit view controller can learn which to edit.  However I can't seem to figure out how to change the value.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Load the plist into a mutable dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *plist = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"file.plist"];
[plist setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"EditThis"];
[plist writeToFile:@"file.plist" atomically:YES];
```