# Property list not copied into document directory

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, plist

I have manually created a property list (Config.plist) using Xcode 4.3 and saved it in "Supporting Files/Config.plist". 
However, when building the project and running the app in the simulator, the property list is not copied in the document directory (as supposed) nor any other directory in the simulator.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: It's copied into the app bundle, not the Documents directory.

Comment: Show us the code where you copied Config.plist into Documents directory. Or have you just dragged it into XCode project and expecting this file to be in documents directory ? No, this file would be in your application bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will go to NSBundle mainBundle by default. You will require to copy that file to document directory. Check my code for copy file to document directory over here:
[Plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335475/iphone-read-write-plist-file/9338807#comment11791131_9338807)

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for the property list at the wrong place. I found it in the app bundle.

Comment: Welcome, If you got the correct answer then can you please upvote and mark correct this answer. Thanks and Enjoy coding :)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot yet upvote because of my low reputation (I just joined StackOverflow), but would appreciate any vote for myself. :-)