# Configuring iOS application with external config file

Tags: ios

I need to be able to configure my app via configuration file.
How do I go about it?
The first thing that comes to my mind is having a .plist file that stores values and to have an singleton class and ask that class for values whenever I create element in question in code.

Or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the amount of content and size of the configuration file. 
If it's a couple of key-value values, I would just go with NSUserDefaults.
If it's a bit more, arrays or more advanced data models, I would go with a .plist. But remember to move the default .plist into the /Documents folder, you are not allowed to edit files in the app bundle.

Comment: How do I edit user defaults from external config file? I ended up using a plist.

Comment: NSUserDefault is not a .plist but actually just a user friendly layer that access a locale SQLite database.

Comment: Yeah, but the question is with using extrenal file

Comment: Check this out, says how you put your .plist into the Documents folder and  read and write in the .plist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335475/iphone-read-write-plist-file